# error on code " org.openqa.selenium.remote.DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below error with my java program:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/CommandPayload;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
    at automation.flyYatra.mainTest(flyYatra.java:42)
    at automation.flyYatra.main(flyYatra.java:243)
```

Tried with adding the latest jar files as can be seen the snapshot below, but could not resolve it. Any help, please?

[image]

package automation;

```
public class flyYatra {

    public void mainTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException, WebDriverException, SocketException {   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Tried with various versions of jar files, but could not solve

Answer (score 0):

Your `various versions of jar files` is the problem known as [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) because in the [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) there are multiple libraries having the same classes and the order of classloading varies depending on the underlying operating system and location of the libraries.

Make sure to have the same version of the Selenium Java libraries, to be more specific the latest one is [3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59)

So I would recommend going for a dependency management solution like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org), you should get the things some using this small [*pom.xml* file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Save it somewhere on your disk and execute [mvn dependency:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) command - it will download a bunch of "good" .jars to "target/dependencies" folder.

You can also use [this repository](https://github.com/seetest-io/java-selenium-first-test) mentioned in [Selenium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+with+Java) article as a basis for your tests